# Problem when inserting strings with special characters

Tags: sql-server

i have a code like this

```
    $query_insert = "INSERT INTO BIBLIOTECA(NOME_ARQUIVO) VALUES ('"$file_name."');
    $instancia = new Conexao();
    $result = $instancia->conectar($query_insert);
```

It works fine, but when the value of $file_name is = 'Contrato Prestação de Serviços' the query inserts in the table the value 'Contrato Prestac¸a~o de Servic¸os'.

Soo i tried to open my MSSMS, created a table for test and execute (i had CRTL+C and CRTL+V on the text to query)

```
INSERT INTO CHAR_TEST (COLUNA) VALUES ('Contrato Prestação de Serviços')
```

and it had inserted the same value 'Contrato Prestac¸a~o de Servic¸os'

but if i delete the value of the insert and and enter it manually then run the query it works fine and return the correct result. Have anyone see this problem before?

Remembering that i alredy have another lines that have the same value (like 'Contrato de Prestação de Serviços Brasil' and another ones like that) and it was inserted perfectly

Here's a few infos about the column that im trying to insert into

**Grouping:** Latin1_General_CI_AS
**fill status ansi:** True
**data type:** varchar
**system type:** varchar

Comment: Please tag the programming language you’re using as well as the settings on connecting etc. It’s inserting in UTF8 at least. Might be ok or not

Comment: Use `nvarchar` as your column type. Related post [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36081/write-differences-between-varchar-and-nvarchar)

Comment: SQL Server does not support UTF-8, but it most definitely "supports" SQL injection, which you're inviting here. Use parameters, and specify the parameter type correctly as `NVARCHAR`. Your database driver code, if properly implemented, should take care of the rest.